# How to prevent access to _VTI_BIN folder on SharePoint and we are using content search query Webpart?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

We are Using content search query Webpart to preview site content on SharePoint and when we prevent access to _VTI_BIN for security reason we run the search crawler a new contents doesn't show up in the search query web part.

Answer (score 0):

Prevent _vti_bin folder access is not supported in SharePoint, as SharePoint needs to make calls to this folder eg ListData.svc web service, you should contact with your security coworker to specify this point, here is a similiar question for your reference:

[Restricting access to contents in “_vti_bin” for both authenticated as well as anonymous users](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/167264/restricting-access-to-contents-in-vti-bin-for-both-authenticated-as-well-as-a)